# Keycloak is failing to start in docker container

Tags: docker-compose, dockerfile, keycloak

During the work with the latest version of keycloak, I had a problem with loading the image.

docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  keycloak-postgres:
    image: postgres:13
    env_file:
      - keycloak-pg.env
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          memory: 512M
        reservations:
          cpus: '0.25'
          memory: 256M
    volumes:
      - postgres_data_keycloak:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    networks:
      - keycloak
  keycloak:
    build:
      context: ../../
      dockerfile: installation/dev/Dockerfile
    env_file:
      - keycloak.env
    volumes:
      - ./config/cache-ispn.xml:/opt/keycloak/conf/cache-ispn.xml
      - ./config/keycloak.conf:/opt/keycloak/conf/keycloak.conf
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          memory: 512M
        reservations:
          cpus: '0.25'
          memory: 256M
    depends_on:
      - keycloak-postgres
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
    networks:
      - keycloak
networks:
  keycloak:
volumes:
  postgres_data_keycloak:
    driver: local
```

my dockerfile

```
FROM quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:20.0.3

ENV HOME /opt/keycloak
ENV THEMES_HOME $HOME/themes/base/admin

RUN mkdir /opt/keycloak/keys

COPY build/resources/main/theme/base/admin/resources/partials /opt/keycloak/themes/base/admin/resources/partials
COPY build/resources/main/theme/base/admin/messages/ $THEMES_HOME/messages

RUN cat /opt/keycloak/themes/base/admin/messages/admin-messages_en.custom >> /opt/keycloak/themes/base/admin/messages/admin-messages_en.properties
RUN cat /opt/keycloak/themes/base/admin/messages/admin-messages_ru.custom >> /opt/keycloak/themes/base/admin/messages/admin-messages_ru.properties


ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/keycloak/bin/kc.sh", "-v start --optimized"" ]
```

I'm getting an error when starting the container.
I assumed that the problem was in my SPI plugin, but after removing it while creating the image the problem picked up again.
docker-compose up

```
 Feb 20, 2023 2:34:03 PM org.hibernate.resource.beans.container.spi.AbstractCdiBeanContainer stop
 INFO: HHH10005004: Stopping BeanContainer : %s
 ERROR: Failed to start server in (production) mode
 Error details:
 io.quarkus.runtime.configuration.ConfigurationException: One or more configuration errors have prevented the application from starting. The errors are:
   - No value present
   - No value present
```

How can I solve the problem

Comment: If i don't use tag -- optimized 

2023-02-20 09:40:01,291 DEBUG [io.quarkus.deployment.QuarkusAugmentor] (main) Beginning Quarkus augmentation
2023-02-20 09:40:01,517 TRACE [io.quarkus.bootstrap.classloading.QuarkusClassLoader] (main) Class quarkus.properties not found in parent first load from java.net.URLClassLoader@671a5887
2023-02-20 09:40:01,517 TRACE [io.quarkus.bootstrap.classloading.QuarkusClassLoader] (main) Class quarkus.properties not found in parent first load from java.net.URLClassLoader@671a5887